# How can I efficiently construct a CFG from a language

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I am new to CFG's and automata in general and I came across an exercise where I needed to construct a CFG for the language {a^m b^n | n <= m + 3}.

So m can be infinitely bigger than n but n can only be up to 3 more bigger than m and they can be the same. I have no idea how to make a CFG for this.

What I came up with was:

```
S -> AB | _ 
A -> a | aa | aaa | C | _ 
C -> aC | a | _
B -> bB | b | _
```

But I think this is not even close...

Any help/tips/advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE. What exactly make you think `this is not even close`? Is $b$ in the language of the grammar above?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to learn is to look at examples, and see how they work.

One of the simplest "real" context-free languages is $\{\; a^mb^n \mid n = m \;\}$

Its grammar is $S\to aSb\mid \varepsilon$.

Now add in steps, the extra 3, and the more than ...

$\{\; a^mb^n \mid n = m+3 \;\}$

$\{\; a^mb^n \mid n \le m+3 \;\}$

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain my thought process behind thinking about this problem here:

-> With inequalities, I first think at the equality constraint. So I assume n = m+3

-> Now, n is always 3 more than m.

-> I split the problem further. I think to myself okay, let's have one production handle equal production of a and b.

-> How many more b's do we need after this? ( 3! )

-> I include that in the start symbol.

-> To end it, I know, n = m+3 is not a hard rule. It is <= . So, I make another production that produces infinite number of B's.

Grammar:

```
S -> Abbb 
A -> aAb | B 
B -> bB | e   ( e is lambda or epsilon )
```